# Shapefile and KMZ/KML point validation in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, kml, esri-geodatabase, validation

I have a KML/KMZ and a shapefile. The shapefile and KMZ have the same number of points. Example would be power poles.

The problem is that, for example, these two power poles have the same attribute information but the points are off by 500ft or so. Basically I need to correct the KML/KMZ based upon the correct location of the shapefile.

Comment: Provide some code or images to help improve your question

Comment: You've tagged this with `esri-geodatabase` but only mention shapefiles.

Comment: which projection is the shapefile in?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the projection. What I need is a script made that will fix the points of the KML based upon a shapefile. If the KML is at (1,2) and the shape file is at (1,1) then the kml needs to be fixed based upon the SHP